# NSCollectionLayoutSupplementaryItem shows below cell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I added a badge using the code in WWDC. But the badge shows below the cell. 
Then, if I scroll, it flickers and sometimes becomes visible, other times stays in the back.
Is this a bug?

```
 let badgeAnchor = NSCollectionLayoutAnchor(edges: [.bottom, .trailing], fractionalOffset: CGPoint(x: 0.3, y: 0.3))
            let badgeSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(30),
                                                  heightDimension: .absolute(30))
            let badge = NSCollectionLayoutSupplementaryItem(
                layoutSize: badgeSize,
                elementKind: "Tick",
                containerAnchor: badgeAnchor)

            let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize,supplementaryItems: [badge])
            group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem:item, count: sectionLayoutKind.columnCount)
```

Comment: Please add the code where you are adding the badge to the cell.

Comment: Ok I added it. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a series of tests, change `section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior` to `continuous` or other behavior, It can cause this bug, should report this bug to apple

```
let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
```

[image]